# Convert a MonoTouch.CoreMedia.CMTime variable with CMTimeGetSeconds method

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to convert a MonoTouch.CoreMedia.CMTime variable in seconds. In native code, the solution is simple:

```
CMTime duration = ...
double durationinSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(playerDuration);
```

But I am not able to find the same method CMTimeGetSeconds in the MonoTouch API. Somebody can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this method isn't bound (nor any of the other CMTime methods). I will look into fixing this.

In the meantime it should be easy to calculate yourself:

```
double durationInSeconds = (double) playerDuration.value / (double) playerDuration.timescale;
```

The actual function also takes care of invalid/indefinite/infinite time values, depending on your need you'll have to take that into account too.

Answer (score 0):

Now it will be simply:

CoreMedia.CMTime duration = ...

duration.Seconds;

Answer (score -1):

Add *CoreMedia.framework* to project